# Barrier Option with Time-Dependent Rebate

Tags: options, option-pricing, exotics, barrier, pricing-formulae

Is there a closed form solution for American Single-Barrier Options (specifically Down-and-Out Calls) which undergo linear principal amortization based on the amount of time passed before being KO'ed?

The Paper *Closed Form Formulas for Exotic Options and Their Lifetime Distribution* by Raphael Douady discusses BOOST options which are somewhat similar.  I suppose the principal amortization could be thought of as a linear time-dependent rebate / coupon, but the BOOST options mentioned are Double Barrier Options with both an upper and lower barrier and the rebate formulae aren't linear.

Also, the Paper *Structuring, Pricing and Hedging Double-Barrier Step Options* by Dmitry Davydov and Vadim Linetsky discusses Simple (Arithmetic) Double-Barrier Step Options, but from what I understand, this only comes into effect when the Stock Price is at or below the barrier and I am trying to value one-touch options which will cease to exist once the threshold is crossed.

Comment: There's a formula for DOC, and there's one for one-touch coupon/rebate, the sum of these two is the DOC with rebate. A time-dependent rebate is a combination of one-touch rebates with different maturities. For example 1 rebate if hit between 0-1y and 2 rebate if hit between 1-2y is a 2-year one-touch 2 rebate minus a 1-year one-touch 1 rebate. This can be generalised easily.